# Quarkus JDBC connection with SSL

Tags: ssl, jdbc, quarkus, agroal

I using quarkus with Panache + Agroal.

I need to setup a DB connection(postgres) with `SSL` enabled. So I need to somehow configure the `server-cert`, `client-cert` and `client-key`.

I only see this available for the reactive client.

Can this be achieved for non-reactive one? I find it very hard to believe that nobody needed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify it via JDBC url. Different database would have its own way to config ssl. For postgres, it would be `sslcert` and `sslkey`, ref https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#ssl

Comment: Thank you a lot! You made my day.

Comment: @N.Silviu remember to mark it as answer for the others